# Irreducible polynomial of prime degree

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Consider the polynomial
$$
  f(x) = x^{p} + x^{p-1} + \ldots + x + 1
$$
over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $p$ is a prime number. Is it true that $f$ is irreducible?

Comment: $x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \ldots + x + 1$ is always irreducible when $p$ is prime See [Cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if $p=2$.
No, otherwise: $-1$ is a root then.